# What windows licence can I purchase to run a web service in intranet?

Tags: licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

One of my customers wants me to provide my web-app to be installed in his local area network, behind the firewall - it will not be accessible from the Internet. They require the server to be run on windows (linux is not acceptable). What windows licence shoud I purchase to run my web-based app for 400 users not violating Microsoft licencing terms?

Comment: You should not. Your customer should. You then install your web app on their server.

Comment: Well, yes that is the way I would like it to be. However they asked me to prepare complex offer with necessary hardware and system licences and it has to be Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

For web apps the simple **Web Edition** of Win 2008 is sufficient - even for 10000 user. That is the same as for the public internet.

Answer (score 0):

It is SQL web edition that is limited to public facing servers

Answer (score 0):

If the users will be anonymously connecting to the website then you can just put the web edition... I think, however I've never put a site of this type up so I've never checked out the details.

If they will be authenticating against it then you will need CALs, if you are going to be using ms sql server behind the webpage then you will also need cals for sql server.

Its quite likely that the client already has cals which will cover them as its an intranet, but if you are putting in win 2008 and they only have win 2003 then you will need to spec new cals for 2008.

In short, you need to investigate the options carefully and read the licencing small print.

Emma has loads of useful nuggets on MS licencing: http://ladylicensing.wordpress.com/ - it'll give you a headache though.